# Can we Optimise the travel distance in VRPTW by using only one Vehicle?

Tags: optaplanner, heuristics, np-hard

Is it Possible to optimise the VRPTW by using only one vehicle.Since the single vehicle must go to the customer  in sequence of the appointment time of customers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. In the VRPTW example, simply add only 1 Vehicle instance in the Solution's vehicleList.

Academically, that's more a TSP(TW) than a VRP(TW) though.